# Looking for information on "Schwartz Toy Mfg. Corp." and products

Tags: united-states, industrial-history

I found a stuffed animal in my attic of a masked mouse with a label having "Schwartz Toy Mfg. Corp." on it.  The spelling differs from FAO Schwarz, and I can't find much on Google except a few sites selling vintage toys.  Is "Schwartz Toy Mfg. Corp." the same company as FAO Schwarz, or perhaps a knock-off?  The item looks pretty old and feels like it's stuffed with a harder material than today's plush stuffing. I'd like to find out more about it, but definitely interested in the company if it's not FAO Schwarz. See images below.

[image: Tag Front]
[image: Tag Rear]
[image: Stuffed Animal Front]
[image: Stuffed Animal Rear]
[image: Stuffed Animal Side] (click to enlarge)

**UPDATE 1**:

I contacted the Astoria Historical Society, as suggested, and here is their response.  The search continues!

> First thing is that it has a zip code so the toy was made after 1963.
>   today would be zip code 11106 which would be the area called
>   Ravenswood.
>
> I quick look up shows that the company was made in Brooklyn 32, which
>   today is 11232 - the Bush Terminal area.
>
> I have no further information - there are old phone books in libraries
>   that could help you find an address, but I would suggest discussing on
>   on one of those forums that have sprung up on the internet which
>   discusses just about anything. There must be a 100 discussion groups
>   on toys, and they generally welcome inquiries and help searches.
>
> Good luck! You find anything do share it with us.
>
> Bob S. Astoria Historical Society

Here is a map of that area:
[image]

Comment: Is there a companies register or similar? Try there

Comment: I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Any declarations of taxes submitted in NY etc? Staff benefits system? Must exist somewhere...

Comment: Here's a breadcrumb: "L.I.C. 11106" is Long Island City, zip code 11106. I can't find anything surviving with that Company's name online, but there is a [Greater Astoria Historical Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Astoria_Historical_Society) dedicated to the history of that area. I'd highly suggest contacting them.

Comment: @T.E.D. I didn't pick on up L.I.C. = Long Island City.  I thought it was short for "License" :)

Comment: @JohnManko - That was my knee-jerk as well, but the second thought was "Wait a minute... that would be Lic. Search engine...WTH does L.I.C. stand for?"

Comment: @T.E.D. I added an update to my post.

Comment: It might be a complete coincidence but there was a [Schwartz Chemical Company](https://www.macraesbluebook.com/search/company.cfm?company=329263) based in 50-01 Second Street, Long Island City, NY, 11101-5703. Their products included "Stitch bonding machines, Knitting machines, Weaving machines, Finishing machines, Spinning machines" which sound useful if you're making stuffed toys. So the toy company could be a subsidiary, perhaps?